# Vue 3 + Vue Router 4: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue 3 + Vue Router 4 + TypeScript.

And I'm trying to use `router.push()` but I keep getting a console error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** If I run `console.log(router);` it returns `undefined`. Therefore I assume this is the problem, but why is that happening and how to solve it?

Here is my `router/index.ts` code:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Welcome",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "Welcome" */ "../views/Welcome.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/chatroom",
    name: "Chatroom",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "Chatroom" */ "../views/ChatRoom.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

And here is the Vue file where the error `router.push()` error is generated from. I have tried using a named route and a path, both give the same error:

```
<template>
  <div class="welcome container">
    <p>Welcome</p>
    <div v-if="showLogin">
      <LoginFormVue @loggedIn="enterChat" />
      <p>No account yet? <span @click="showLogin = false">Signup</span></p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <SignUpFormVue @signedUp="enterChat" />
      <p>Alredy registered? <span @click="showLogin = true">Login</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import SignUpFormVue from "@/components/SignUpForm.vue";
import LoginFormVue from "@/components/LoginForm.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const showLogin = ref(false);
const enterChat = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router); // <-- This returns undefined. Why??
  router.push({ name: "Chatroom" });
  //router.push("/chatroom"); <-- This also doesn't work, gives the same error
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out.

The `const router = useRouter();` line needs to be outside the `enterChat` function. For some reason you cannot create the `router` instance inside the same function you wish to use it.

So it should be like this:

```
const router = useRouter(); //<-- router declared outside function: CORRECT
const enterChat = () => {
  router.push({ name: "Chatroom" });
};
```

And **not** like this:

```
const enterChat = () => {
  const router = useRouter();//<-- router declared inside function: INCORRECT
  router.push({ name: "Chatroom" });
};
```

Here is the full updated file for reference:

```
<template>
  <div class="welcome container">
    <p>Welcome</p>
    <div v-if="showLogin">
      <LoginFormVue @loggedIn="enterChat" />
      <p>No account yet? <span @click="showLogin = false">Signup</span></p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <SignUpFormVue @signedUp="enterChat" />
      <p>Alredy registered? <span @click="showLogin = true">Login</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import SignUpFormVue from "@/components/SignUpForm.vue";
import LoginFormVue from "@/components/LoginForm.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const showLogin = ref(false);
const router = useRouter();
const enterChat = () => {
  console.log(router);
  router.push({ name: "Chatroom" });
};
</script>
```

Comment: I had `router` defined outside the function. Still, it happened. Try declaring it at the top of the file